# How to export AEM tags into Excel

Tags: java, tags, aem

Yesterday I had to export all **AEM tags** into Excel file. While surfing for the best solution to do this, I've found out that almost everyone advices writing custom code that takes all of tags and enters it into **Excel** file.

I consider that solution good, but since there are a lot of people that do things like this for the first time and it will probably take some time for them to figure out how to do this.

For them, let's share some workarounds for this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a comma separated list of tags I would recommend using the command line, the build-in [AEM query builder](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/querybuilder-api.html), `curl` and `jq` (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

**The general approach:**

1. Use query builder to build a JSON representation of `/etc/tags`
2. Use `curl` to "download" the JSON
3. Use `jq` to "parse" the JSON and create a CSV

**Example:**

Exporting all tags below `/etc/tags` with their path, title and description would look like this:

```
curl \
    --user admin:admin \
    --silent \
    "http://localhost:4502/bin/querybuilder.json?p.hits=selective&p.limit=-1&p.properties=jcr%3atitle%20jcr%3apath%20jcr%3adescription&path=%2fetc%2ftags&type=cq%3aTag" \
    | jq --raw-output '.hits[] | [."jcr:path", ."jcr:title", ."jcr:description"] | @csv' \
    > tags.csv
```

This would send a `GET` request to your local AEM instance (`http://localhost:4502`), authenticate as user `admin` with password `admin`(default settings for AEM), use the query builder API (`/bin/querybuilder.json`) to get all resources with type `cq:Tag` below `/etc/tags` and of those resources it would "select" the properties `jcr:path`, `jcr:title` and `jcr:description`.

The resulting JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "results": 2,
  "total": 2,
  "more": false,
  "offset": 0,
  "hits": [
    {
      "jcr:path": "/etc/tags/experience-fragments",
      "jcr:description": "Tag structured used by the Experience Fragments feature",
      "jcr:title": "Experience Fragments"
    },
    {
      "jcr:path": "/etc/tags/experience-fragments/variation",
      "jcr:description": "A tag used by the experience fragments variations",
      "jcr:title": "Variation"
    },
  ]
}
```

Next, the command above will pipe the resulting JSON from the query builder to `jq`, which will use the "query" `.hits[] | [."jcr:path", ."jcr:title", ."jcr:description"]` to read only the `hits` array and of every item in that array only `jcr:path`, `jcr:title` and `jcr:description`. The resulting arrays are then used as input for `@csv` "string formatter" of `jq`, which will create proper comma-separated output.

The JSON from above would be formatted to:

```
"/etc/tags/experience-fragments","Experience Fragments","Tag structured used by the Experience Fragments feature"
"/etc/tags/experience-fragments/variation","Variation","A tag used by the experience fragments variations"
```

The last part of the command `> tags.csv` will just redirect the output to a file called `tags.csv` instead of the command line.

AEM has a query builder debugger which you can use to create queries that you then can use in your command line command:

http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html

The query parameters I used above would look like this in the tool:

```
path=/etc/tags
type=cq:Tag
p.hits=selective
p.limit=-1
p.properties=jcr:title jcr:path jcr:description
```

You can add properties as you like, but for them to show up in the CSV you also have to update the query used by `jq`.

If you add translations to your tags they will be stored in a property called `jcr:title.<language-code>`. If you translate your tags to German for example, you would have two properties: `jcr:title` and `jcr:title.de`. If you want the translation you have to extend the `p.properties` and add `jcr:title.de` etc.

Comment: Very nice! I didn't know for this option and I think it answers this question even better than my answer.

Comment: Is there an option to get how many times is every tag referenced this way?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to export tags, here is simple solution on how to easy export them and then there are several ways how to import it in the Excel, without need to write custom code for this.

**To export AEM tags do the following 5 steps:**

> 1. Open [**package manager**](http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/index.jsp)
> 2. **Create package** (give it some meaningful name)
> 3. **Edit** created package
>
>    - Select "**filters**" tab
>    - Enter **path** to tags you wish to export (for example: http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/tagging/gui/content/tags.html/etc/tags/geometrixx-outdoors)
>    - you can find it under Adobe Experience Manager -> Tools -> General -> Tags
> 4. **Done**, **Save**
> 5. **Build** package
> 6. **Download** Package

Then you have all tags inside **{download_package_name}/jcr_root/etc/tags**.

Now there are **several** ways of getting downloaded tags to Excel file. This is how  to do this on Windows -

Source: [Is there a way to export a folder structure into excel?](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/6y9p28/is_there_a_way_to_export_a_folder_structure_into/)

> Find the folder in Windows Explorer, then Shift Right click on that
>   folder and select "Open Command Window Here". Type the following
>   prompt:
>
> dir /a /s /b > filelist.txt
>
> That gives you a text file saved in your top folder, which you can
>   open in notebook, then copy and paste into an Excel document.

Answer (score 2):

There's a GUI in AEM to export content as excel [well almost]. To get a tsv file of tags in the system AEM's bulk editor can be used. Navigate to '/etc/importers/bulkeditor.html' on the server. Set path as '/etc/tags' or a subtree. In query field type 'type:Tag'. Select the properties that need to be exported and hit search. The results can then be exported to a tsv file via the export button.

[image]

References

- https://helpx.adobe.com/in/experience-manager/6-4/sites/administering/using/bulk-editor.html
- https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/commons/search/GQL.html

Comment: Is there a way to get how many times is every tag referenced this way?

Comment: try https://localhost:4502/etc/tags/experience-fragments.tags.json?count=true. This endpoint will give the count.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the privileges to comment on the accepted answer but thought it would be useful to add to the excellent accepted answer: If you're on >= 6.4 then you may need to change the path in your query to /content/cq:tags (1) or query both paths if your install has been upgraded over time and you have long lived tags. I was getting 0 hits even though I could see several hundred when viewing http://localhost:4502/tagging

(1) https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-experience-manager/tagging-issue-in-aem-6-4/qaq-p/320994

Hopefully, this non-answer isn't overly frowned upon.